# Google Sheets SUMIF and ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

[image: Data example]

What I'm trying to do is to sum row 1 in column D if A3:C has a value. The blue cells in the image shows the values I'm trying to calculate.

```
=SUMIF(A3:C3;">0";$A$1:$C$1)
```

or

```
=SUM(FILTER($A$1:$C$1;A3:C3>0))
```

does just this, but then I have to drag the formulas down. I want to do it with ArrayFormulas since the number of rows is growing but I can't figure out how. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
In the real data there are many columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=arrayformula(ArrayFormula((A3:A>0)*A$1)+ArrayFormula((B3:B>0)*B$1)+ArrayFormula((C3:C>0)*C$1))
```

or a bit shorter when written as:

```
=arrayformula({(A3:A>0)*A$1}+{(B3:B>0)*B$1}+{(C3:C>0)*C$1})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are many, many columns, which makes that solution a bit cumbersome. I do think you're on to something that might work. `=ArrayFormula((A3:C>0)*A1:C1)`, results in an array that could be summed row by row?